# Nvidia HDR Encoder

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, nvidia, hdr

I'm trying to use the [NVIDIA SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk/download) to encode HDR video with H265. Windows Media Foundation doesn't (yet) support 10-bit input with H265.

I can't seem to feed the colors correctly to the encoder. I'm trying to render a video which has 3 images, one green with a value of 1.0, one with value of 2.0 and one with value of 3.0 (maximum) in the RGB, that is, in D2D1_COLOR_F it's {0,1,0,1}, {0,2,0,1} and {0,3,0,1}.

Only the maximum 3 is seen correctly (The left one is the generated video, the right one is the correct color that should be shown in the video):

[image]

With green set to 2.0, this is the result:

[image]

And with green set to 1.0, even worse:

[image]

And this is the result of a real HDR image:

[image]

The Nvidia encoder accepts colors in AR30 format, that is, 10 bits for R,G,B and 2 for Alpha (which is ignored). My DirectX rendered has the colors in GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat so I'm doing this:

```
     struct fourx
     {
        float r, g, b, a;
     };

    float*f = pointer_to_floats;
    for (int x = 0; x < wi; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < he; y++)
        {
            char* dx = (char*)f;
            dx += y * wi * 16;
            dx += x * 16;
            fourx* col = (fourx*)dx;
            DirectX::XMVECTOR v;
            DirectX::XMVECTORF32 floatingVector = { col->r,col->g,col->b,col->a };
            v = floatingVector;

            // float is 0 to max_lim
            float max_number = 3.0f; // this is got from my monitor's white level as described [here][6].

                DirectX::PackedVector::XMUDECN4 u4 = {};
                col->r *= 1023.0f / max_number;
                col->g *= 1023.0f / max_number;
                col->b *= 1023.0f / max_number;

                u4.z = (int)col->r;
                u4.y = (int)col->g;
                u4.x = (int)col->b;


                u4.w = 0;
                DWORD* dy = output_pointer;
                dy += y * wi;
                dy += x;
                *dy = u4.operator unsigned int();
            }
          }
```

I suspect something's wrong with the gamma or what.
I'm not sure how to proceed from now on.

Comment: The RGB color space isn't linear. If you need to scale RGB color values, convert to a linear color space first, perform the scaling, and then convert back to RGB. I guess that is the issue, but who knows what the code does or is supposed to do. It's incomplete, littered with magic numbers, comes without explanation and the only reference to supporting documentation is `[6]`. Gee, that's helpful.

Comment: @IInspectable it's obvious what the code does, it scales the RGB from [0,3] to [0,1024] linearly.

Comment: The Microsoft article you've linked to only refers to the windows compositor, it uses a linear encoding. You'll need to convert to a standard HDR gamma encoding and write which encoding you've used to the video file's metadata. OpenColorIO will help you with the conversion

Comment: WIC floating point RGB is (implicitly) using scRGB https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-codec-native-pixel-formats#color-space so needed conversion is a bit more complex, but if you use WIC, just use a WIC Converter to GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102 or GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppBGR101010 and push to NVenc (you can also use NV_ENC_BUFFER_FORMAT_ABGR10)

Comment: @SimonMourier this clamps the input bitmap to [0,1] instead of the original [0,3]. `CreateBitmapFromMemory` with `GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat`, to create a WIC bitmap from my buffer, `CreateFormatConverter` with `GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102`, `WICBitmapDitherTypeNone`, `WICBitmapPaletteTypeCustom`. So for green 3.0 it produces 10 bits 1111111111, and for green 1.0 it also produces the same bits.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "green 3". GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat stores 0=>1.0f and conversion to GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppRGBA1010102 will work fine to 0 => 1024 (uint) with scRGB transformation. You can try this (c#) to see conversion working https://github.com/smourier/WicNet/blob/main/WicNet.Tests/Program.cs#L57

Comment: @SimonMourier I mean that my buffer is HDR, range from 0,0f to 3.0f for each color. That's how it's drawn in Direct2D bitmap (GUID_WICPixelFormat128bppPRGBAFloat). Why do you say it stores from 0,1?

Comment: What about WIC then? But anyway you just need to normalize 0=>3.0f to 0=>1.0f  and then 0 =>1024 (uint) with scRGB